# DotNetNuke Error System.NullReferenceException during upgrading DNN

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

getting following Error System.NullReferenceException during upgrading DNN:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.get_Status() +78
   DotNetNuke.Entities.Urls.RewriterUtils.OmitFromRewriteProcessing(String localPath) +39
   DotNetNuke.HttpModules.RequestFilter.RequestFilterModule.FilterRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) +207
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +148
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

Comment: what was your start and upgrade version, what step did it stop at during upgrade.  Did you use the auto upgrade or initiate it manually.  We need more info to help you.

Comment: I'm having this same issue after upgrade from 6.1.5. The upgrade had no errors but I got this when I hit View Website and try to go to any of the pages.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by comparing the web.config of a fresh install of 7.1.2 to my upgraded instance. I made a lot of changes and I'm not really sure which one made the difference but it does seem the problem is with an incorrect web.config setting.

Answer (score 0):

I used the solution posted [here](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/forumid/200/threadid/473761/scope/posts/threadpage/4)

"Edited web.config and replaced all entries of 3.5.0.0 with 4.0.0.0 (yep, replaced all)"
Then I performed the upgrade and did not encounter the error this time.